# How does one determine if ObjectForScripting has been set for a WPF WebBrowser control from javascript?

Tags: javascript, wpf, webbrowser-control

Is there a way to determine if the ObjectForScripting property of the WPF WebBrowser control has been set via javascript running in said control?  Or, is there a way to determine if the ObjectForScripting has a given method or property defined via javascript?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If ObjectForScripting is not set, `window.external` will be `null`.

```
if(window.external === null)
    alert('ObjectForScripting is not set');
else
    alert('ObjectForScripting is set');
```

To check if `ObjectForScripting` has a specific method/property, just check if it's undefined or not.

```
if(window.external !== null && typeof window.external.MethodName !== 'undefined')
{
    // Method exists
    window.external.MethodName();
}
```

Comment: When I check for window.external in a Chrome session, Window.external is not undefined.